# Oracle DB size decreased after import

Tags: oracle, datapump

My database size was 1TB and its full export size is 300GB.

After imported db to new environment, db size reduced to 700GB.  What could be reason for this ?

Comment: This happens as a matter of creating nicely contiguous extends within an Oracle database.  After a while, a database gets fragmented because of updates, deletes, etc.  Exporting and then importing allows data extents from data and undo to be more contiguous, show less used space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be many reasons.
But generally, it may be due to:

- Free space in data files or temporary files
- Undo data
- Row chaining and migrating
- Data blocks fragmentation

Answer (score 2):

Check the size of your `temp` tablespace and the `redo` tablespace. The reduction may come from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I would expect of any good RDBMS.

A database that has been used for a long amount of time will fragment. Your efficiency of the fragmented database is 70%, which I would say is pretty good.

When importing the data into a fresh database, there will be no fragmentation, but after you have deleted and inserted lots of rows, you will see fragmentation will hit you again.